# How to extract data with particular key from parsed json?

Tags: python, json

I have parsed json data like below:

```
{
    "results": {
        "authors": [
            [
                {
                    "person": "Person1 Name",
                    "key": "director"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "person": "Person2 Name",
                    "key": "author"
                },
                {
                    "person": "Person3 Name",
                    "key": "author"
                }               
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I.e. there can be several directors and several authors. I should get it as string like:

```
directors = "Person1 Name"
authors = "Person2 Name, Person3 Name"
```

Looks like I should go thru each value and check its `key`. But how can I do it with simplejson?

Comment: Actually it is almost JSON, minus the single quotes. JSON requires double quotes, and the syntax is nearly similar to Python's `dict`

Comment: Sorry, that was json, but I've already loaded it.

Comment: Can you not structure your data better to remove the need for the "key" attribute? For example you could have 2 arrays inside the results object - one for authors and one for directors.

Comment: @larsmans, first one - Person1 Name is director. Please see the key.

Comment: @MitchS, this is 3rd party data, I can not change it.

Comment: @LA_: ah, sorry, missed it. I was confused by the `"authors"` key.

Comment: you'll have to tell whoever is providing the data that the structure is terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
authors = []
directors = []
for persons in movie_json.get('results').get('authors'):
    for person in person:
        if person.get('person'):
            if person.get('key')=='author':
                authors.append(person.get('person'))
            elif person.get('key')=='director':
                directors.append(person.get('person'))
authors = None if authors == [] else ', '.join(authors)
directors = None if directors == [] else ', '.join(directors)
```

Answer (score 3):

To extract data from a json structure, you can use the `jsonpath` module. See http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/. I am not the author of this module.

Your code would look something like this:

```
directors = jsonPath(json, '$..authors[?(@.key=="director")]')
authors = jsonPath(json, '$..authors[?(@.key=="author")]')
```

You will need to extract the names and join them together, but I think you will find that easy enough.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do it with simplejson? I use Google App Engine and simplejson is built-in there.

Comment: `jsonpath` is ported to python, see: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath/. To use, simply copy the module file into your project directory.

There is no easy way to query json data using `simplejson` only.

Answer (score 0):

I think your json design is wrong.
You should make json like this:

```
foo =    {
        "results": {
            "directors": [            
                        "person": "Person1 Name",
                ],
            "authors":[                
                        "person": "Person2 Name",                 
                        "person": "Person3 Name",
                ]        
        }
    }
```

Now if someone ask for directors do

```
directors = ','.join(foo["directors"])
```

and authors

```
authors = ','.join(foo["authors"])
```

thanks

Comment: the arrays for `directors` and `authors` are displaying data as objects (with key value pairs). You either have an array of items or an object with key value pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my data, I can not change it. Please also note that this is json data already parsed with simplejson.